# Переименовать файл удалив все что идет после вхождения + само вхождение

Tags: python

Переименовать файл удалив все что идет после вхождения + само вхождение (Python)

(для примера) Есть файлы с названием типа:

```
19625361_12022-09-27-09-32-31.jpg
```

и

```
241849332022-09-27-09-34-59.jpg
```

Где

- `19625361_1.jpg` то что нужно получить и удалить дату и время `2022-09-27-09-32-31`
- `24184933.jpg` то что нужно получить и удалить дату и время `2022-09-27-09-34-59`

Уникальное вхождение у всех файлов это **`2022-09-`**

Подскажите как это сделать ?
Файлов огромное количество.

Answer (score 0):

1. Само переименование файлов в Python выполняется функцией `rename()` из библиотеки `os`.
2. Выделение нужного фрагмента в строке, в которой находится имя файла можно делать по-разному, например через регулярные выражения. Но я бы использовал тот факт, что дата у вас всегда занимает 19 символов (включая тире). И расположены они всегда перед последней точкой (или если все файлы jpg - то непосредственно перед строкой `.jpg`). То есть удаляете последние 23 символа в строке, а к тому, что осталось добавляете `.jpg`
3. Поскольку *"Файлов огромное количество"* то понятно, что описанные выше действия оформляете в виде цикла, который последовательно просматривает ваш каталог с файлами, на каждой итерации вытягивает очередное имя, делает описанное выше преобразования и переименовывает файл.

Вообще говоря, эта задача для второго урока по Python, как только выучили строки и начинают учить циклы. Так что надеюсь -  справитесь дальше сами. Ну или в учебник все-таки загляните.

P.S. Дополнение в связи с тем, что ТС решил Python не учить, но задачу все равно делать.

Состояние директории до выполнения скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт:

```
import os
dir = r"D:\Загрузка\s1" 
files = os.listdir(dir) 
for  file in files:  
    new_file = file[:-23] 
    os.rename(dir + '\\' + file, dir + '\\' + new_file + '.jpg')
```

Состояние директории после выполнения скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! И метод решения с удалением последних 23 символов Гуд.. плз.. напишите эту строчку кода которая это все делает)) Проблема в том что я знаю что Пайтон решает такие задачи но я не программист и скорее всего буду использовать пайтон только в этом случае))

Comment: @FaridFarkhadov Например так `new_name = name[:-23]`

Comment: @ZxNuClear

dir = r"E:\maklerxana\Marko-test"
files = os.listdir(dir)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    new_file = file[:-23]
    print(new_file)

Comment: Чтобы я не делал чтобы переименовать файлы ничего не получалось (( os.rename(dir + '\\' + file, dir + '\\' +  new_file + '.jpg')

Comment: @Farid Farkhadov  Вы неправильно делаете главное - пытаетесь решить задачу без изучения возможностей инструмента. Что именно у вам не получается??? Внес дополнение к моему ответу выше -  смотрите. Там все получается!

Comment: @passant
Я понял в чем была проблема У меня были файлы 19625361_12022-09-27-09-35-55 и 19625361_22022-09-27-09-32-32 тут разница в названии файла 09-32-32 и 09-35-55... На выходе после отсекания [:-23] название файла получалось одинаковым и выходила ошибка

Comment: @Farid Farkhadov Я рад, что у вас все получилось. Кстати вам, как новичку, подсказываю:  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers